# Has the post-closing grace period gone?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, posting

I was writing an answer to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188954/155739) a moment ago and, perhaps 10 seconds before I submitted it, I saw a notification in the corner of my eye. It turns out that this notification was for the question having been closed as a dup. Well, fair enough, we shouldn't be posting on dups and, generally speaking, we can't.

But in this case it was *annoying*. I'd just spent my time writing a nice little post, for free, only to find a fatal block at the final hurdle.

I'm sure the "Post your Answer" button used to remain enabled and you'd still be able to submit the post, within a short grace period, to avoid this rude annoyance. But this time the "Post your Answer" button, I *think*, was disabled as soon as that notification came up.

What's changed?

Comment: Could you post your answer to the duplicate?

Comment: @RichardTingle: Yes, of course, but (a) it is redundant on the duplicate, and (b) that is not the point of this question.

Comment: I also wondered when it happened a while ago  but assumed the grace period is until the heartbeat code is running which is every minute or so. Trying to reproduce now to check something. Hint: I suspect it was always like this, users [simply bypassed the client side only check](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160753/152859).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: It used to work for me, without bypassing anything. [Robert's comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160753/post-answer-after-question-closed-and-banner-shows#comment466390_160753) confirms that this was the intended behaviour, but it's evidently changed now.

Comment: Oddly enough, this just seems to have been answered by [an hour-old post on a 7-month old question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188971/155739).