# Shouldn't there be any way of reviewing the edit reviews?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, review-abuse

Sometimes my edits are rejected for no good reason. A good example is when I add a new major tag (like asp.net) to the question, and the edit is rejected for being a too minor edit. Adding an asp.net tag is not a minor edit. Everyone should know that.

By the way, this question does not have anything to do with the one suggested here. The only thing I can think of they have in common are the words "review" and "audit". That question is asking what audit reviews are, but my question is actually a suggestion on having a guideline for reviewing edits, or having an audit of edit reviews.

---

Note this question **[only looks similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773)**, but is essentially different: [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)

As opposed to above question, this one is asking if there's a way to review reviews. The goal is the same as review audits (to improve the quality of reviewers), but the mechanism is different. Also, review of reviews is an active mechanism and review audit is a passive mechanism.

To put it simply, let edits be E and reviews be R. Review audits is still reviewing E (except that the E is not a real edit), whereas here I am asking whether there is anything to review R.

Comment: Can you post a couple of examples?  If there were other things that needed fixing in the post, just adding the tag *is* too minor.

Comment: A question that is related to asp.net, should be tagged as an asp.net question. Why is that a minor edit? asp.net is a huge category.

Comment: An edit should fix everything that is wrong with the post.  It is definitely important to add the tag, I agree with you, but if you are going to take the time to put the tag in, give the post a once-over as well.  If you've done all you can, there's no real reason why someone should reject it.

Comment: The request for samples is a good one. An edit should be as complete as possible, not the minimal possible.

Comment: It is true some edit reviewers are very lax and will accept any edits that are general improvements and some are very strict and want the editor to fix every problem or think a lot of work is due for the 2 points to be earned, but this variability is controlled somewhat by requiring several reviews for each edit. Often 3-5 reviews are examined before the algorithm reaches a decision.

Comment: My understanding is that some reviewers think that when only a minor edit is needed to the question, you shouldn't even bother with editing it. But, I think most of people who have commented to my question agree that the point of rejecting an edit because of it being too minor is to encourage people to edit as much as they can.

Comment: Here is a sample: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2784412.
This edit was eventually approved, but two people rejected it for being too minor. I had just added an asp.net tag, and there was not much else to edit.

Comment: There's a lot in that question that could be fixed in terms of capitalization and other grammar, I think.

Comment: I agree with you, but that's the other thing. A lot of people do not care about grammar and punctuation fixes. They don't consider those important either.

Comment: I don't think anyone would reject an edit for doing too many grammatical improvements.  I think you're confusing people that may be "roboreviewing" with those who are actually being conscientious about it.

Comment: Also, if I want to fix all the grammar and punctuation mistakes, I'll have to edit almost every single question.

Comment: Well go for it!  At least do what you can when you come across it, I think that's all anyone is really asking.

Comment: @ataravati Yes, and? What’s your point about “editing every question”? That’s what we do on [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com), you know. Almost every question there gets edited for spelling, grammar, punctuation, formatting, and general spiffiness.

Comment: I just thought that a lot of people on SO wouldn't like that. But, I was probably wrong.

Comment: @ataravati Please do: it makes the site look more professional that way.

Comment: @gnat This question has nothing to do with review audits actually.

Comment: @OldCheckmark are you kidding? Primary goal of [meta-tag:review-audits] is to prevent review errors like those pointed by OP. _"Test items in review queues that are designed to help new reviewers hone their moderation skills, while nudging more experienced users that don't seem to be paying close attention to what they're reviewing..."_

Comment: No, I mean this question is asking if there's a way to review reviews. The goal is the same as review audits (to improve the quality of reviewers), but the mechanism is different. Also, review of reviews is an active mechanism and review audit is a passive mechanism.

Comment: To put it simply, let edits be E and reviews be R. Review audits is still reviewing E (except that the E is not a real edit), whereas the OP here is asking whether there is anything to review R.

Comment: @OldCheckmark I see, thanks. As far as I can tell, this is just your interpretation. If (note: _if_) it would be so, it would (note: _would_) indeed be not a dupe... [similar but essentially different](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773 "see explanation in 'outcome #2' here"). Think is though, [as of now](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/194535/revisions), nothing in the question indicates that it's the case

Comment: @gnat No, that's not his interpretation. I would like to know how you think my question is a duplicate of the other question. These two questions have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate either, but you might consider changing the title. That's what appears to be confusing people. It's the only place you ever mention "audit", and "audit" has a very specific meaning around here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the commenters here have argued, improving any grammar/punctuation problems that you see in the post is always a positive improvement, and a good way to ensure that your edit will not be rejected as "too minor" by any of the reviewers. And you should definitely pluck the low-hanging fruit while you're going through the trouble of editing, like [removing "thanks" and other signatures/salutations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts?lq=1).

But [you are still right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194535/shouldnt-there-be-any-way-of-auditing-the-edit-reviews#comment611811_194535): adding a *major* tag like ASP.NET to a question is a *major* edit and *should not* be rejected as "too minor". Those reviewers who voted to reject the edit made the wrong call. Please don't let this deter you from continuing to labor in improving the site for everyone!

And to answer the question in your title, shouldn't there be any way of auditing the edit reviews—there is. You've already found it, the proper place is the Meta site. Unfortunately we cannot go back and approve audits that have already been rejected, but we can let you know if you're on the right track or not. And provide some helpful suggestions on how to improve. Which is really the whole point of the suggested edits system, to serve as training wheels for future [editors-at-large](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).