# Will people make fun of me if I flag/close my own question?

Tags: discussion, flags, closed-questions

I am not talking about reputation points... I'm talking about what is customary to do. I don't want to be the laughing stock of the Stack Exchange community for doing something that is considered weird by many.

Is there a Stack Exchange policy for how to not be ridiculed?

Comment: Yes. [Exhibit A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367969/what-would-the-evaluation-order-of-x-x-x-be#comment2343717_2367969).  That said, let them make fun.

Comment: @BilltheLizard That's what we call "justice" or "democracy", I guess. You did the right thing and I am sorry they made fun of that.

Comment: I have 5 duplicate questions between MSO and SO, and I've voted to close 3 of them, 2 of which I've been the first vote.  But no one makes fun of me (at least to my face).

Comment: I've flagged my own questions for closure before, its not a big deal.

Comment: Frankly I think you should be applauded for doing so. I have done so myself, I received no applause. *world's smallest  violin plays*

Comment: I think the first person to flag their own post as spam should get some sort of prize however

Comment: @RichardTingle if you do that, someone will try to do that (despite the 100 rep penalty)

Comment: "fun" tag . . . awesome. More posts should be "fun".

Comment: my [bragging about self-closure here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773) got decent amount of upvotes and bounty. I guess this means it's generally considered OK _"In cases like this I flag / or vote to close my own question myself."_.

Comment: @Richard Tingle: You can't, anyway, unless you use a custom flag or a sock puppet. And in case anyone was wondering, no, you don't have to try it because yes, at least one other person has tried each of those methods.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with flagging/voting to close your own question if you realize it should be closed.  It may be considered unusual, but it is by no means bad or wrong (either by the rules, or just guidelines).

Of course, if possible, it's also best if you can improve the question such that it no longer needs to be closed, but voting to close it until that's done is perfectly fine.

Probably the most common case is when you find, or are shown, a duplicate.  Voting yourself only further clarifies that the proposed duplicate is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: In fact, you gain the privilege to vote to close your own questions long *before* being able to vote to close other questions.

Comment: I would only add that closing your own question could be considered a sign of maturity rather than a reason for derision. It shows that you're adult enough to recognise when you've asked a duplicate and to help "fix" the problem. Everyone who's been around here long enough has done it so there's nothing to be ashamed of.

Comment: @benisuqbackwards arguably you could even say your overall actions were a good thing (not just correcting a mistake) because some duplication is a good thing as it leads to more search routes in

Answer (score 7):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with closing your own question or marking it as duplicate. It only shows that you didn't just post the question and wait for answers but also went on some research work.

Answer (score 4):

You...

> "What if someone makes fun of me?"

Me to you...

> "What if they don't?"

^^^ Focus on that kinda thinking.

**2 answers:**

**Specific advice:** If someone thinks it's ridiculous that you show you actually learned something, *then that's their problem*, not yours.

**Life advice:** *Don't do (or not do) something because you're afraid*... of what the world, or someone in it, *might* do. *Might*.

The guy that outright berates you for doing either of these things has his own problems.

Your question is based on pure speculation; it's nothin but stinkin thinkin. Don't let fear run your life. Have a set, grab em, *do what you think is best.*

Comment: The question could easily be modified to ask, "Is it considered acceptable behavior to close your own question?" without really changing the answer.

Comment: I'll bet you meant that comment for the OP? Even so, it's clear to me that the poster is less concerned about the technical aspects of it than the effect it will have on their person. They don't want to be made fun of.