# How is my question a duplicate?

Tags: support, specific-question, duplicate-questions

I recently asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440811/how-to-install-ipa-file-on-iphone-simulator) and it was marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517463/how-can-i-install-a-ipa-file-to-my-iphone-simulator).

If you look at my question description, it states that I have been trying to install the application and was facing some issues while doing so. But the other question, of which it was marked as duplicate, deals about installing application on the simulator.

Can some please explain how it is a duplicate and kindly consider it for reopening?

Comment: voted up doesnt seem duplicate,but the reviewer's might considered duplicate due to title of both the questions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Someone flagged my question as already answered, but it's not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not)

Comment: @gnat i have modified the title,and i have rephrased the question too,i posted here just to bring notice its not duplicate of the question whatever mentioned over there

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but fundamentally both issues boil down to

**Q**: "How do I run a .ipa on the simulator?" 
**A**: "you can't".

You got slightly further with a bodge that give an illusion of progress, but it doesn't resolve the fundamental arm vs x86 problem still.