# Why do questions without answers appear in "No Upvoted Answers"?

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions, no-answers

I see why there are some questions which don't have any answers, but still they exist in category "No Upvoted Answers". Why? These questions should be in category "no answers".

> [image]

Comment: No answers `=>` no answers can be upvoted `=>` no upvoted answers. Problem?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be parsing this English phrase incorrectly. "No upvoted answers" does not mean answers that are not upvoted, it means the absence of upvoted answers.

Naturally, if a question has no answers, it also contains no *upvoted* answers,

Comment: There is tab see "no answers" then what is for ?

Comment: Questions without any answer at all. There _is_ overlap between the two, and that's ok.

Answer (score 3):

#### Who will browse this list?

- One who is looking for answers will not see this list as obvious.
- One who wants to answer questions.

So why do one who wants to answer look at questions which have zero score answers and not look at questions without any answer?