# Question marked as duplicate when they are not duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Even the questions are different from each other, i found one question is marked duplicate making not able to answer on both question. Not able to answer the question on duplicate marked question because of restriction and another question because of inappropriate place to answer.
Can we [**flag->other (needs ♦ moderator attention) -> comment**]
If not so how do we request mod to remove duplicate mark on such question.

The question i am unable to answer due to duplicate mark is [How to kill unity panel & unity launcher? [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47022/how-to-kill-unity-panel-unity-launcher)
And I am sure the answer of any question to another question does not help this question.

Comment: related: [Someone flagged my question as already answered, but it's not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not)

Answer (score 4):

1. Edit the question to make sure it is clearly distinct from the assumed duplicate
2. Add a great edit summary / comment explaining the change
3. Wait for it to pass through the reopen review queue

If you ask, *"How do I foo the bar?"* which gets closed as a duplicate of another question asking how to foo the bar, and you feel that your question is not a duplicate because it is asking how to foo the bar under condition baz which isn't discussed or considered in the first, edit your question to make that distinction clear. You can even add a link to the question it was closed as a duplicate of saying, *"I have read through this similar question, but it doesn't explain how to foo the bar given condition baz"*.

Then make sure you make a clear edit summary and attached comment saying something like, *"Updated the question to clearly distinguish it from the question it was marked as a duplicate of: [Question marked as duplicate when they are not duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232032/)"*. That will make it clear to people who see the edit or review it that you have made a significant change that requires close reading.

Since an edit will automatically migrate your question to the reopen review queue, you can just wait for that to happen. If it doesn't happen in a week, you can consider asking for a review on meta or in chat to help the process along.

Answer (score 2):

If they're really two different questions, bring it up on your site's meta or, if it's trivial to point out the difference, flag it for moderator attention and explain how they're different in the flag message.

Optionally, also leave a comment explaining how the question is different from the one it was closed as a duplicate of.

Answer (score 0):

The measure of whether a question is a duplicate is not just whether the *question* is a duplicate, but whether the question is *similar* to another and the answer is the same.

In this case the [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/q/47022) is wholly answered by the [linked question](https://askubuntu.com/q/46788).

Comment: The answer isn't the same. The linked question's answers _contain_ the a portion of the answer to the former question, which an answer to the former would also contain, but the whole answer would not be the same in both questions. The difference isn't large and noticeable when it's a small answer, but [in cases where the answers are lengthy](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/1070/5573), the difference becomes important.