# Mutli-accounts and own up-voting

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts, serial-voting, multiple-accounts

Recently I got the following strange situation:

I accidentally lookup at a user's reputation and realized he has lost over 670 reputation on account removal. More suspicious is that he gained between 19 Jul and 27 Jul 80-120 reputation per day. That gives him over 1000 reputation in less than 10 days. In last 2 months he gained only 500 reputation. Moreover: this user has only 14 answers and questions with 9 upvotes in last one month. The upvotes was done on his previous questions.

Primary I was about asking mostly about tools that were able to detect such users. This part of my question was answered by @ChrisF and it was most adequate to my thoughts.

Now I realized no one answered to my second question part (maby I didn't made it clear): What an ordinary user can do in such situation. If any ordinary user have a any option to react in such situation? User can in some way know something more than machine and might help moderators to detect such situations.

For now the answer is: nothing. And I don't think flagging his post is an option.

Comment: If the user lost reputation on account removal, the *moderators have already dealt with the account*.

Comment: @Szu just like on the main site, saying "Nope" does automatically make the question not a duplicate.  Do you care to explain why and what might be missing or not answered?  FYI - The threshold for duplicates on Meta sites is much different than on main sites simply because there is more discussion in comments (and links to the SO Blog - which is probably what answers your question more than the duplicate itself).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Comment: Okey I updated my question. Are you satisfacted? For me writing such question is not wasting 5 minutes but much more. I don't wanted to waste time on this question especcially when you already marked it as duplicate.

Comment: OK, not a dupe anymore, at least not of this one. Anyway, users can earn even 500 rep every day in legit ways. There is nothing we can or should do apart of maybe going over the answers and learn how to post good answers. :)

Comment: But I am not poiting how much user user gain per day, but the changing trend. When user get 10 points per day for over year and urgently gain 100 points per day something is wrong. PS: can you paste a link to that possible duplicate in my answer as related to my answer?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but the tools are not available to ordinary users.

There are tools and processes in place that can detect this sort of behaviour and if we find it votes are invalidated and/or accounts deleted to deal with it.

If this has happened you will see a large drop in someone's reputation.

However, it's perfect possible for someone to legitimately earn the over 100 points per day so that's no indication that voting irregularities have been taking place. Given there's a good chance you might get it wrong it's probably not beneficial to flag it up to the moderators. If there is something bad happening there's a good chance they know about it already.

Comment: I really don't think I am wrong. How do you explain that user was gaining 10-20 points per day since 18 Jul, and now he gain over 100 not for new but for old questions?

Comment: @Szu - given the points have been removed you were probably right in this case, but that sort of rep gain can be legitimate - which is all I'm trying to say here.

Comment: @Szu Prime example of what ChrisF is trying to say: [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet). I can't remember the last time I saw Jon earn *less* than 200 rep in a single day...

Comment: I understand, but is there any way to report such user to moderators by ordinary user?

Comment: @Szu - you could flag one of their posts with the "other" option, but as I said there's a good chance we'd already know about it.

Comment: @JonK Jon Skeet but 1000 points is not 30% of his total points. A understand I can be wrong, that's why I ask for a tools that allow to help me to analyze his votes or tag user as suspicious to help moderator in their work. Any way thanks.

Comment: @JonK: It last happened in June 2010, I believe.

Comment: @JonSkeet Was the internet broken that day?