# How do I participate in a question when I have a low reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, comments, questions, duplicate-questions

I have a question similar to an existing one. I would comment, but my reputation is too low. How do I participate to that question? Should I answer, edit or start a new question that may be marked as duplicate?

Comment: @gnat: The respective duplicates are (in a rather wide sense) about answering a question with low reputation – not about asking one.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Answer (score 3):

There are some cases to distinguish:

- You are looking for something different than the existing question does: Ask a new question, in which you refer to the existing question and make clear why your’s is different – this should avoid closure. (Also make sure that answers to the existing question does not contain the desired answer as a side-product.)
- You are looking for the same thing as the existing question and it has already been answered to your satisfaction: There is nothing to do, you have your answer.
- You are looking for the same thing as the existing question and it has not been answered to your satisfaction. There is nothing you can do to provoke an answer – except gathering sufficient reputation and placing a bounty on that question.

The above may be somewhat idealistic but should reflect the intentions behind the system. Even though, I can hardly conceive a situation in which comments are the best way to solve your personal question.