# Do I have to edit my question to contest a possible duplicate flag?

Tags: feature-request, support, duplicate-questions

[A question of mine](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20905/116625) has been marked as a possible duplicate of [a related question](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20428/116625).

This would be fine, since they really are quite similar and I would gladly [edit my question to explain why it isn't a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/267636), if only I hadn't already done exactly that. I asked my question specifically because the other question left some open ends and I wanted to clear those up. Most of the question body is already me explaining what the difference between the two questions is and why this question deserved to be asked separately.

I have already added a comment explaining this, but it seems I can't contest this flag without editing the question:

[image: Question]

I could edit in even more explanation as to why it's not a duplicate, but I honestly don't see that improving the question in any way. I could also make a minor edit without changing the content of the question, but that would feel like gaming the system.

Is there any way of getting rid of this flag without editing the question?

**Edit:** As it turned out, the distinction between the two questions wasn't quite as clear as I thought it was, so I've opted to edit my question. This does, in a sense, solve my issue. I still feel that being able to say: "No thanks, my question is fine as it is." would be a useful option though.

Comment: ['what's the best way to prevent these "helpful" flaggings in the future?'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773)

Comment: @gnat, I came across your answer while trying to figure out if this question had been posed before. It was a very good read and definitely helped me to some extent. I didn't mind the flagging itself much really, what bothered me is SE telling me it was flagged and making that actionable (good) but not in a way that I felt I needed.

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't have to. If you don't agree on a vote to close (which I can't see, I just see the answer being *flagged* by a low-reputation user), just leave a comment to one of the voters why you disagree, as you did. Maybe you can even invite the user in chat (if he/she doesn't want to, just leave it! Don't harass the voters).

Also, there is more than one vote required in order to close a question. If more users agree, you are possible wrong in your opinion. If not, it has the chance to get reopened any time.

I would advise to update the question to emphasize more it is about the *description*, and not the *title*, that is what got me confused on first sight.

Comment: You might be right (though I disagree). But this doesn't answer my question. I stated why I think a new question was warranted, if someone disagrees with what I said, simply flagging as a possible duplicate without any explanation isn't helpful. And I should be able to contest this flag. If you want to discuss if the question is a duplicate or not, I invite you to do so on the actual question.

Comment: @overactor: please see my updated answer.

Comment: I would edit in the title of the question in, instead of disguising it in your own sentence. Something like *In the question [Expand name to include both Free Software and Open Source?](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/20428/expand-name-to-include-both-free-software-and-open-source/20462#20462) the last sentence of the higest upvoted answer states...*

Comment: @rene That is a good suggestion. It is a little ambiguous now.

Comment: Worth to mention that only the first voter (by leaving an automatic comment) and the last voter (having the binding vote) can be pinged via a comment, not any voter.

Comment: @Sha indeed. Not sure how it works if it gets flagged, that's why chat is an option here.

Comment: Sure, I just responded to "just leave a comment to one of the voters" which might lead to a "zombie" comment that will never reach the target user. :)