# Closed duplicate threads up for reopen need a reason disputing the closure

Tags: feature-request, review, duplicate-questions, vote-to-reopen

This is a frequent problem in the Reopen queue. A question is closed as duplicate. Unlike the most common reasons for reopen (editing to add more to the question), these are near impossible to discern in some cases. Here's an example

https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/8591273

So the OP edited his question and cleaned it up, but there's no comments or edits saying why he doesn't think it wasn't a duplicate. I'm inclined to leave it closed because it doesn't address the duplication but there's something to be said that the user who posted this probably doesn't even know he has a dispute running by making the edit.

What I would like to see is a comment box (or even a note) in the edit window of closed duplicates that says something like this

> Your question has been closed as a duplicate of **Some Other Question Link Here**. You can edit your post, but unless the question is reopened, you will not receive any answers. Your edit can trigger a vote to reopen, but voters will need to understand why you do not think this question is a duplicate. Please enter a comment as to why this is not duplicate.

This helps

- Voters understand what the difference is so they can make an informed decision
- Newer users to understand the closure and reopen process for duplicate questions

Comment: first, they are not threads. Second, closed is not locked. You want to change the terminology, but you don't know the terminology. This causes me cognitive dissonance.

Comment: Updated the question with correct terminology

Comment: progress, but the advice still needs tweaking. For example a comment is not as good as including it in the body. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not/