# Require at least one true moderator to close a question deemed duplicate by a privileged user

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-answers, dupehammer

Though this suggestion might be way over the top with questions that are ''blatantly off-topic'', there may be easily some **bias** involved with duplicate ones, shown as follows.
Just look at mine: [How to handle spaces in path names when variable contains multiple paths](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183417/how-to-handle-spaces-in-path-names-when-variable-contains-multiple-paths)

This is so evident that a pair of glasses should *not* be a requirement: "...in **path** names...". This question, which seemingly already has an answer elsewhere, is about *paths*, whilst the other question is about whitespace in *files*. So it proves, that sometimes the asker (me :P) *can* read, while another user (who has been given the "super-power" privilege)  has obviously only skimmed over the question, doing 5 things at the very same time, temporarily lacking the powers of focusing to *one* thing. (Some do seem to be lacking these powers very often, by the way. :P)

But, what is even more interesting, is that Gilles was the **lone wolf** to mark this question as "duplicate". Normally, there would be at least 3 true moderators (NOT privileged users, but *elected* moderators) thinking the same way.
And, the way this whole system is structured, there is not even a way to discuss this with Gilles by writing him a private message. Discussing this *on* the question page would be inappropriate as well, so the privilege-less asker just has to live with the privileged user's **capriciousness** (or had I better even use a political term, *despotism*?)

Again: Since one, by design, cannot *directly* contact a "lone wolf" about why he made that decision (which may even be in error, mind you!), there should be a requirement of at least 3 (+1) votes from true moderators that a question may really  be deemed duplicate.
Otherwise, one lone wolf might easily misuse the powers he was given (just by amassing reputation, not by election, mind you!) and enjoy the way of letting his capriciousness reign all over the place.

*"To err is human."* And hence, it should not happen that said human may legitimately close a question *in error*, whilst other (elected) moderators would think otherwise (but were never asked in the first place).

What do you think?

Comment: You can contact the *lone wolf* because @-reply in comments works for users that suggest edits AND for Close voters that dupe-hammered. Those usernames don't auto-complete so type carefully... and your assumption about *real/elected* moderators is wrong. Their single vote will be binding. You want 3 regular users with close vote privileges to vote on your question.

Comment: That's NOT what I'd define as "contacting" at all in my question! Contacting means to contact them *directly*, __user to user__! Otherwise the "Wikipedia effect" will come up: I reply to the *lone wolf*, and 10 other users (some of which can never stop mingling in other people's affairs!) would mingle in, even though this hasn't got anything to do with them. Hence I consider the direct contact so incomparably useful.

Comment: We are not a social network, so that would be a no from me...

Comment: @syntaxerror *What do we think?* I guess we think this is more of a rant, than a productive question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Someone flagged my question as already answered, but it's not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not)

Comment: I see this was closed because it only applies to a specific site. Which one please? As far as I see, it applies to all, including this one.

Comment: @DaniSpringer It *does* apply to all. But the question mentioned in the first section of my original post belonged to U&L. And many thanks for your concern. It is good to find some sane mind on here, from time to time ;-P However, you against 1000 nerds who simply verbally reproduce the stuff of their predecessor ("Napoleon is always right")...this is gonna be a difficult task. Anyways - thanks for stopping by.

Comment: We shall keep going till stopped! :) You're welcome.

Answer (score 11):

First, Gilles isn't a moderator. He is a normal user with a gold tag badge in one of the tags on the question.

Holding that badge makes him an expert on the subject and earning that badge also means he earns some trust. He can instantly close questions as duplicate of others. That doesn't mean he or others can't reopen it is deemed appropriate.

The dupe-hammer is a very nice feature that often brings a lot of good. Sometimes a users makes a mistake, like we all do. Just edit the question and explain why it isn't a duplicate of the other question, and the question will come in the review queue. Other users have the ability to vote to reopen then. It will take 5 users to reopen it, or one vote of a gold tag badge holder.

Comment: Ehh? You can't be serious, that would be OT! Let alone that it would clutter up the question text with junk. Anyway, thanks for the reply. I might try to __flag__ my question instead, though. But I won't edit it, writing in something that does not have anything to do with the question itself, for sure! That would be just silly.

Comment: Don't flag. It will get declined. Just edit your question. If it gets reopened, just edit it out. See it as clarifying your question, which is on-topic.

Comment: Well, OK...fair enough. And thanks to your explanations, I've managed to improve my wording in the title. I think the title has made the question way more logical now. Oh, and I am too intellectually challenged to follow your sentence *That doesn't mean he or others can't reopen it is deemed appropriate.* ;P For real, I always switch to `tl;dr` mode when there is too much (redundant) double negation. ;) Let alone that the people using it sometimes confuse themselves, turning the sense upside down w/o knowing it.

Comment: True, more than once I reopened a question I closed with the hammer.

Comment: Me too. Often due to unclear wording of OP, sometimes by own fault.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for the edit. HAHA despite the mass of downvotes I got from this so far (I guess from privileged users, think of the *dog doesn't eat dog* principle in politics :P), I had to laugh hard since I didn't know about an existing "dupehammer" tag. Funny.

Comment: @syntaxerror yeah, "you suck, I don't trust you" tend to irritate people, what can I say