# How do I offer my answer as the answer when the ability to do is not present?

Tags: discussion

I helped someone out with a question and yet I cannot post my response as the answer. There is already an answer there, but that answer did not help the person asking the question.

What do I do to get my answer as an answer that can be checked off as an answer?

Comment: Why can't you post an answer? Is the question protected, on hold/closed, something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about this question: [Do I need to have sendmail installed in order to use the mail() function in my contact form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46383379/do-i-need-to-have-sendmail-installed-in-order-to-use-the-mail-function-in-my-c/46383440#46383440)

You can't answer it because it's closed as a duplicate. If you feel that it's *not* a duplicate, you can flag it to reopen and explain in the comments why you think it should be reopened. You can also edit the question (or the person who asked it can) to explain why it is not a duplicate.

More information about dealing with duplicates that you disagree with on Kate Gregory's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194479/284336).

If it **is** a duplicate, you can answer the question on one of the duplicate questions - assuming the identical solution is not already posted.

As it stands, though, this is how the site is supposed to work. Questions that are closed - for whatever reason - can not be answered.

Comment: *"you can flag it to reopen"* - there is no such flag and OP doesn't has enough reputation to _vote_ for reopening.

Comment: thank you, I wasn't sure if it had to do with it being flagged as duplicate or not and I would not be able to reopen as @Tom stated. What does OP stand for?

Comment: @Tom You can flag anything for a moderator's attention and explain why you're flagging. An *edit* to the question (by anyone) will put it in the reopen queue, too. "OP" stands for "Original Poster" or "Original Post".

Comment: I hardly think a moderator would reopen the post due to custom flags. Mods aren't there to decide that and shouldn't be called for that stuff.

Comment: @Tom *as a moderator* (though not on Stack Overflow) I'd say that, if a question was *obviously* not a duplicate, I'd be more than happy to reopen it. My advice is in line with the advice that's been given out on SE for years. See Kate's linked answer to see.

Comment: @Catija The question was closed by somebody with a gold badge in “php” so in this case the question is a duplicate.  Which is fine the author should answer the duplicate if they have an answer.  I obviously agree a moderator would correct a incorrectly closed question though.

Comment: @Ramhound Sure. From reading comments on the answer, it wasn't clear to me whether the dupes actually addressed what ended up being the problem. An edit to clarify the difference (if there is one) is always a good option.

Comment: @Catija I trust a user with a gold badge on a tag, didn’t take a look myself, I just notice that it was closed.  I still agree a flag to a moderator would be appropriate