# Remove duplicate on someone else's post

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

I was testing an answer locally on someone else's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350493/loop-program-back-to-start-point-after-its-finished) recently, only for it to be marked (in error) as duplicate.

Whilst I can see why the duplicator (for want of a better word) did what they did; it did basically address one issue the OP was having, but IMO not the main issue.

I wanted to remove the duplicate tag, but there isn't a clear answer of how to do this.

I thought of using `@` on one of the duplicator's posts, and letting them know before removing the comment, but thought that was an odd way to do it.

I figured flagging it would get a moderator to remove it, but it got declined as a request `declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention`.

I read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194479/375723), but this feels like it's what the OP should have done, not a random answerer.

How should I have done this?

Comment: Why not just ask on SO meta or chat? The user has 250000 reputation, it should not be hard to find them.

Comment: You can always @-reply the editors and the dupe hammers on a question

Comment: They left no comment or otherwise, so I would have thought @ would not have worked. They were not hard to find, but didn't feel right asking them to re-open one question on an entirely unrelated question.

Comment: Excellent, I never spotted that duplicate. It pretty much explains everything!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is already a mechanism in place for this: the vote to reopen.

However, you need to have 3k reputation before you can cast such a vote (and actually that reputation in order to close a question). Question opening and closure requires a fair amount of experience so the reputation threshold is set accordingly. Being able to close and open a question as a duplicate is possible in one vote if you have a gold badge on one of the tags. Again, this requires experience so the reputation level is set high for that (a minimum of about 10k).

In this particular case the closure looks to be the correct action. The question doesn't really add much value in the context of a Q & A site.

So if I were you, I'd set this aside, and continue contributing to the sites in other ways: you can reach 3k in about a month at full pelt.

Comment: Whilst I disagree that the question should remain closed, I do appreciate the answer. I was also unaware that there is a 'vote to re-open' option at a certain threshold.

Comment: Also - I agree that this one can be left alone at this stage; it's more for future reference in case a similar situation arises.

Comment: There is no minimum reputation required to hold a [gold badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) in a tag. Gold tag badges require >=200 answers in a tag and >=1,000 tag score. It's possible, but very unlikely, that you *could* get a gold badge with a rep of 1. For example: 1,100 upvotes on answers in 1 day, giving +200 reputation (max per day) and a tag score of +1,100; then, 100 downvotes on the other 199 answers you need for a gold badge (-200 reputation, net 0 rep & +1,000 tag score). Presumably, you'd still need the 3k reputation in order to be able to cast close-votes at all.

Comment: Indeed: I was exquisitely careful with my language: for a gold you need 1000 votes which is 10k but of course you might have downvotes on other tags which reduces the threshold. Then there are reputation caps to consider etc..