# Extreme caching issue allowing answers to closed questions

Tags: support, bug, closed-questions, caching

4 hours ago (at 15:53:08UTC today), I closed [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224195/implement-%ce%94list) question over on CodeGolf.SE. We've discovered before that it's possible to answer a few minutes "under the line" due to caching before, simply by not refreshing the page. For example, [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224208/66833) answer was posted at 15:59:08UTC.

However, a few minutes ago, somehow, [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224222/66833) answer was posted, *4 hours after closing*, which lead to general confusion in our chat room, along with [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57739245#57739245) thought:

> if the closure check is client-side could one theoretically just disable it an post an answer to an already-closed challenge? and if it isn't cilent-side, how is Neil able to do that if it should be closed server-side already o.O

by [hyper-neutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyper-neutrino).

A few minutes of caching isn't much of an issue, hours of caching potentially is.

Is this a problem?

Comment: ^ https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79434/why-was-an-answer-allowed-on-a-question-that-was-merged-into-another-one/79457#79457 they beat it by ~ 2 minutes.

Comment: Thoughts of rogue userscipts allowing answers after closure are flashing through my head now... I'm inclined to imagine that it *still* wouldn't be much of an issue though, even if it was moderately common. It's *very* detectable, and repercussions could be doled out to user(s) who started purposely abusing it for whatever reason.

Comment: If it actually requires the answer to have already been in the process of being written, the potential of this being reliably abused is... extremely small, but it's unclear if that restriction is client-side or server-side.

Comment: With JQuery and a console, literally anything is possible.

Comment: Three SEDE queries for those wanting numbers on the frequency of these: #1 for [all post-closure answers on a site (sans obvious merges)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1400094/answers-posted-after-question-closure), #2 for [grouping such posts by author](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1400122/ops-of-post-closure-answers), and #3 for [grabbing such posts for a specific user](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1400128/post-closure-answers-posted-by-user). The champion on SO has 149 post closure answers (of their 13k+ answers lol).

Comment: This is not a bug. The server has a deliberate “grace window” of several hours in which answers are still accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's still [possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79434/why-was-an-answer-allowed-on-a-question-that-was-merged-into-another-one/79457#79457) to answer a closed question within 4 hours.  That user just squeaked in.  Here's when the question was closed:

[image]

And here's when the question was answered:

[image]

So they just beat it, about 3 hours 58 minutes after it was closed.