# is it ok to ask for checkmark

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you feel dirty if you nudge new users to accept your answer when they indicate you've answered their question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicate)

If you answer a question, and you know the answer is correct because the OP indicates that your answer solved there issue, is it ok to prod for upvote/checkmark?

I recently had this happen on a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060052/string-in-grails-arent-strings/6060298#6060298).  The user is new so Im not sure they quite understand how SO works....

Comment: There are some hi-rep users here that would burn you in a fire and cut you into little pieces if they could just for suggesting this. As for me, go ahead! I think everyone has the right to claim for that little gratification that we deserve for our effort.

Comment: well i definitely feel a little dirty for asking. but hey, i spent time and helped them, so.....

Comment: And now you got your question closed. This is so hilarious!

Comment: @yms, yeah, i actually searched for the title, but nothing applicable came up.

Comment: @yms, It's ok to let them know about how accepted answer works only if they're __new__.  Please don't harass everyone with 'accept me' answers.

Comment: @Lance Don't worry, I don't, but I still find amusing how angry some people can get about this "issue".

Comment: I promise I'll resist the temptation to cut you into little pieces if you only do this *occasionally* on *really good* answers you've given that the OP actually *confirms* helped them to solve their problem. And after you've given them adequate time (say, a day or so) to accept the answer on their own.

Comment: @cody, yes i definitely feel dirty; i think ive done it like twice, and thats why i am here asking for clarification.  On the other hand, SO is a system that encourages answering questions in exchange for votes and accepted answers. That system has in place mechanisms for getting users to use the system correctly.  However there is nothing in the system that really encourages accepting answers; the only thing that i see happen is people leave 'work on your accept rates' in the commetns to questions from users with low accept percentages.  Could be better.

Comment: I tend to write `You're welcome.  [You should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup.  It is very appropriate and helpful.

If a user doesn't understand how the site works 100%, any guidance you can give is helpful.

Comment: @hvgotcodes Consider upvoting and clicking the checkmark to the left of this answer if you found it solved your problem.

Comment: @adam, ;) lolz...