# I posted an answer after a question was closed?

Tags: bug, answers, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How was this answer posted after this question was closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed)

I saw some odd behavior on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364660/camelcasing-htmlreport-vs-htmlreport/6364699)

I posted an answer after the question was closed and I believe another person after me did as well:

[image]

Comment: Ray didn't post after it was closed.  "1 min ago" is before "41 secs ago". **edit**: ah I see there's another one on there now, and they were indeed both posted after closure

Comment: @Dan look at the question, there is a third one now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tim Stone mentioned in my similar question, linked by Daniel above,

> If a question is closed while you're answering, you will receive a notification that the question was closed and the 'Post Your Answer' button will be disabled. However, this is only a client-side restriction, so it is possible in some cases that this process fails.
>
> When it does, the backend allows for a grace period of around four hours (previously there was no time limit). Presumably the client-side restriction did fail in this case, and since the answer was "in-flight", as Jeff describes it, the server accepted it despite the question already having been closed.

So, basically, if the question is closed while you are writing your answer sometimes the system "lets your off" and allows you to post anyway.