# Should added post notices be live-refreshed with edits?

Tags: discussion, live-refresh, post-notices

I was just on a question page when the grey `an edit has been made to this post - click here to reload` banner popped up.  I clicked it and was presented with the

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   A dupe

box in front of the answer.  Yet there was no closed notice on the post or in the page title and the answer box was still enabled.  I know this is only going to be relevant for closures as exact duplicates (as only these generate a Community edit) but if you've gone to the trouble of loading the changes to the post would it cause a great deal more problem to load the duplicate notice?

This would be more to help out newer users, as they are more likely to start drafting an answer not realising that the duplicate link indicated closure - I tested it out and you could get quite into an answer before the closure warning pops up

Comment: The answer box ought to be enabled still however.  It is by design to allow people to still post answers if they haven't refreshed on a recently closed question AFAIK.

Comment: @JeffMercado I'm not entirely clear on that, as far as I remember the submit button was disabled once the question has been closed notice was displayed.  I guess it would allow you to copy/paste onto notepad in case the question gets reopened?

Comment: I could be wrong on that and things may have changed since then or I just misunderstood what actually happens.  I see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91922) now but it was my understanding that (before live refresh was implemented) you got the close message but you were still able to post.  I know I was able to do that at least once somewhat recently. Whatever was the intended behavior should be done.