# Is it possible to answer a question that has been closed and put "onhold"?

Tags: support

I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20072910/1671639), which is kind of asking about books, and has been close voted and put onhold.  I was the last person that voted to close (at that time there was no answer).

[image]

First, I thought it was a few seconds lag, but the difference is 1+ minutes.

Not sure whether this is a bug or problem with timezone?

Comment: This is likely a dup.  This would happen if one started to answer before the question was closed but _posted_ it after it was closed.

Comment: @devnull server side validation allows to post answer several hours (!)  after question is closed, so someone who knows how to manipulate DOM in the correct way can post answer even without the button available. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Is this still an open issue in SE sites?

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan no, it's by design.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd thanks. Shall I delete this question because what I wanted is answered in this [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed).

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan don't feel obligated to delete just because it's a dupe, no harm leaving it around.