# Found a way to post answer for closed questions

Tags: bug, answers, closed-questions

Yesterday, I asked a question about [answering the closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208027/233367) in which @Sha Wiz Dow Ard mentioned [possible if we manipulate the dom](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208027/is-it-possible-to-answer-a-question-that-has-been-closed-and-put-onhold#comment662972_208027).  First I thought it needs lot of work but here I found an easy way.

1. Wait till the question gets closed.
2. An alert appears, **"no more answers accepted"** and now the **`post an answer`** button is disabled.
3. Via developer tools, I remove the `disabled` attribute and now I tried it worked.

*This approach can be easily prevented I guess so, by hiding the button*.  Not sure about other methods but this seems to be an easy way to answer to closed question.

I have screenshots,
[image]

[image]

Since [its by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208027/is-it-possible-to-answer-a-question-that-has-been-closed-and-put-onhold#comment662996_208027), I guess they won't agree to hide the button.  Anyway just to notify you.

Comment: I think it'd be called a bug

Comment: If you refresh the page is the answer still visible?

Comment: Not a bug, already reported... looking for the dupe.

Comment: Note that *deleted* questions is whole different story... you should not be able to post answer in such case, with our without DOM control. :)

Comment: @Praveen, you can start feature request asking to change current behavior and block such answers, but I for one will vote it down.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Just now looked into the dup answer.  Do I need to change the tag in this case?

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan change what tag?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd inorder to request it as feature, but I can guess that they agree to this(already you don't like it ;) ).

Comment: You mean change this question to feature request like I suggested? No, better be done in new question if you still want.