# Question closed while user is carefully composing an answer

Tags: discussion, support, answers, closed-questions

I spent a lot of time writing what I thought was a good and helpful answer to an [admittedly poor question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20740701/674039), but by the time I had finished writing it the question was closed.  It was a terrible user experience, leaving me annoyed that all my effort to help was wasted!

Is there any way for me to submit my answer on this closed question?  Should I just go and post my answer, late, on some other relevant question instead so I don't feel so burned?  Or should I just live and learn not to bother answering poor questions?

Comment: There is a grace period that allows you to still submit anyway AFAIK. [Though maybe you need to mess around with the browser dev tools to use it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed)

Comment: Generally, if you know a question is likely to be closed, it's not a good idea to invest so much into answering it. You're wasting your own time by doing so.

Comment: Then what is the point of the reversal badge.  I thought the badges were intended to encourage behaviour that the designers wanted to see?

Comment: @wim - it is for those rare cases where a great answer saves a question. That is why it is **gold**.

Comment: The grace period did not work in this case.  I didn't see a banner saying "you have 5 minutes remaining to finish answer this closed question" I saw a banner saying "This question is closed and no more answers will be accepted" or something similar

Comment: @Oded: Wait - saves a question from what?

Comment: @wim you can still submit answer even hours after question is closed by manually enabling the submit button via the browser's dev tools. (usually F12 brings them up)

Comment: Interesting.  Is that still possible now that I've closed the tab?  I don't have the submit button anymore, it's not simply disabled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a "closed" or “on hold” question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question)

Comment: @wim - Your browser doesn't have a reopen closed tabs function? Maybe you can just post it directly to that id. But unless you can improve the question it will likely be a waste of time anyway. Now you have brought it to the attention of meta it may be only a matter of time before it gets deleted.

Comment: Tried that already but couldn't resurrect a tab with even a disabled submit button.  It's probably futile anyway *shrugs*.  I stand by my comment that it was a terrible user experience.  I love stackoverflow and enjoy to contribute here, and it's like the site just gave me the finger  :)

Comment: It's a problem with the Stack Exchange sites and frustrating.  Thanks for trying.

Comment: As an aside, why do people downvote the hell out of stuff here on meta?  Is there something wrong with this question?

Answer (score 12):

> Or should I just live and learn not to bother answering poor questions?

Yep.

Lesson learned?

---

If the question is poor - either vote to close it, or better yet - improve it and *then* answer it.

Comment: How to get the other four answerers to learn also?

Comment: This is one positive behaviour we punish. Helping fix a question first or asking for clarifications rarely outperforms the educated guess answer

Comment: _NO_, if a question can be answered (i.e. it's not so poor as to be ununderstandable) then it should be answered.  What comes around goes around.