# Prevent posting answers to question recently closed or put on hold

Tags: feature-request, answers, closed-questions

This question is a follow up of [How was this answer posted after this question was closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91922/245360), which explains how it is possible that an answer is posted *hours* after it was closed or put on hold.

The current system doesn't really prevent answering bad questions, since the block on posting answers on recently closed questions is just client-side (an in-browser HTML change will do circumvent this).

I think this is bad, especially on sites suffering from bad questions, like SO, but possibly a lot more sites.

I would propose to make this block more strict to prevent answering bad questions.

Some options:

- Prevent answering at all server-side (so if you started typing an answer, your answer will be 'lost' until the question is reopened);
- Auto-flag users that frequently answer closed questions (they might be the users tricking the system);
- Any other suggestion from your side to make this better.

Comment: Is there any evidence this is being exploited?

Comment: (Ahum, yes....) I don't have names @Won't