# How often do questions get answered after they got closed?

Tags: support, answers, closed-questions, data-explorer, grace-period

As most of us know, there is a [grace period for users who started to write an answer and the question got closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91922/245360). This grace period is set to 4 hours server-side. In the web interface though sending an answer is blocked when a question got closed. This will prevent to click the button, but can be easily circumvented by a browser code fix.

I wonder how often answers are posted after the question gets closed. Of course, we have to consider not every user games the system, and I am not after that nor do I want to point the finger at users. It might help though in the analysis on the problems with rep farmers.

Can anyone check the database on these facts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are [7,496](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/338298/questions-that-got-an-answer-after-they-got-closed) answers that were provided to questions that were closed and not re-opened after that. (I didn't fancy writing a query that fiddles with timelines).

There are [6,749](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/338301/unique-question-that-gort-answers-after-closing) unique question that got answers after closing.

You notice in the first query a couple of questions ([this is the topresult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)) that got answers waaaay beyond its closeddate. I suspect merges to be the cause of that but I have to find evidence yet to support that claim.

Comment: The 4-hour time limit was implemented in September 2010. Prior to that, there was no server-side restriction; it was solely client-side.