# Can Community Moderators and Stack Overflow employees post answers on closed questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, closed-questions, moderator-abilities, stack-exchange-team

Since this doesn't appear to have been asked before:

Can elected moderators (and Community Managers, and other Stack Overflow employees) post answers on Questions that have been closed? This would cover either manually reopening these questions so that they could be answered, or simply writing an answer to them despite them remaining closed.

Presumably at least one person at Stack Overflow would have access to the hardware that'd let them do these sorts of things by fiddling with the database, but have these sorts of powers been entrusted to the Community Managers, and other user-facing staff members?

I'm not asking if they will, simply asking if they have the ability to do so.

Comment: Related: ["How was this answer posted after this question was closed?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/).

Comment: It's worth noting that the server doesn't block answers to closed questions until four hours after they get closed. This means that any user (not only mods) can post answers to closed questions within four hours, by working around the client-side disabling of the answer controls or by using the API. However, after these four hours, no one, not even mods or staff, can answer the closed question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, but they can instantly re-open them, answer them, and then re-close them to effectively do so.

It would be rare for this to happen and, if it did, then I would expect any moderator involved to be prepared to explain to their community why they did it.

Answer (score 4):

People with a moderator diamond have moderator privileges. Those privileges include the ability to unilaterally re-open a question, post an answer and then unilaterally close the question again.
This does not give the same effect as answering a closed question, as the re-open/re-close actions will be recorded in the posts history, but it comes close.

Some staff members, which to my knowledge includes the entire CM team, have moderator diamonds on all sites of the network.

Some developers also have direct access to the databases and could directly modify the data there, but that would be an action of very last resort.