# Why can't I post answers to questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: bug, answers, closed-questions

I was trying to post an answer to a question on Stack Overflow but for some reason the frontend (yes, frontend lol) had disabled the button. The button was disabled, so for posting it I had to go to inspect mode and enable the button. I did post the answer haha.

Comment: If I had to guess, because the question was closed (seeing how your answer was posted 3 minutes after the question was closed)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed

Comment: "I did post the answer haha" - You submitted an answer to a question that was deleted.  **You really should avoid answering questions that are caused by a typo.**

Answer (score 10):

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65566453/why-isnt-this-python-code-showing-an-error/65566552#65566552) has been closed while you were writing the answer.

From your answer:

> You probably made a typo

That might very well be the case, but that's a reason to flag the question as 'not suitable for the community', not for posting an answer. You're basically guessing at the problem; that's not the purpose of Stack Exchange. What we need is clear questions and good answers. Your efforts are better spent on questions which *are* clear and useful; there are [plenty of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Unanswered).