# Invisible placeholder-stub-answers-with-autodelete-timeout to avoid "Question closed!" frustration

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, usability, answer-quality

**Motivation:** Once again I spent time creating an elaborate answer on Stack Overflow, only to find the page locked when I was done, because people were not satisfied with the details given. Sometimes though, depending on the reader, the intention is clear enough to help the user. But what can you do? -> Rage quit.

**Argument:** Stack Exchange's very substance, next to interesting questions, is the willingness of random people to invest time to create good answers. But when I ask myself "Should I spend some time on Stack Overflow to answer questions?", I remember my *repeated* deep frustration when not being able to post my work. Consequence: Spitball-ish answers are more likely than elaborate ones. Also ... please consider the unnecessary frustration that could be avoided. We're people after all, not text generators.

**Solution:**

Without any disruption to the site's experience, the feature of **invisible stub answers** could be introduced, where users (about to work in the IDE in service of the community) can reserve a spot that nobody can see but themselves.

Unless the user turns it into a *real* answer within a reasonable timeframe (2 hours? Ideally, the timer should be refreshable a few times.), this invisible stub answer would be deleted automatically.

**Consequence:** No frustration over wasted work on closed questions. No visible clutter caused by this solution. Balance shifting towards elaborate answers over spitball answers. Moderate implementation time. - The only downsides are beyond the 10th decimal place.

Comment: There already is a grace period for 4 hours where you can still post an answer to a closed question, assuming you already started writing an answer. Just remove the disabled attribute from the post answer button.

Comment: @rene: After searching, I get the impression that you're suggesting a client-side hack https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316139/402568 to circumvent the sites' normal behavior. While I'm thankful for the tip, I'm appalled that this is the solution that keeps being proposed in those places. Clearly there's something amiss with the sites' design.

Comment: Within 4 hours there's no need for a 'hack', though. 4 hours seems like enough time to write an extensive answer, and you can always edit in more details afterwards.

Comment: "Within 4 hours there's no need for a 'hack', though." That's exactly the opposite of what the link, and apparently rene, claims. Has the functionality changed since then, or are you not speaking from personal experience / solid knowledge?

Answer (score 10):

Other people are equally frustrated by those who continually try to guess at the meaning of poor quality quesions and who then make a stab in the dark about what the answer might be rather than wait for clarification.

What we're aiming for here are not just high quality answers but high quality questions where their answers clearly match the questions so that when someone is searching for that problem they recognise both the question is their problem and the answer answers it.

The solution for your problem is not to make it easier for you to answer poor quality questions that are on the way to closure, it's for you to learn to recognise poor quality questions, participate in their closure if you like, but mainly to move on and answer better quality questions instead.

Answer (score 5):

I think there's a little more nuance than "People are spending time answering questions that closed halfway" - That's to say *why* that question is closed is important.

If its a question closed as a duplicate and the duplicate target *doesn't* have your solution - there's no issue. You can just post the same answer there, and life is good.

> Once again I spent time creating an elaborate answer on StackOverflow, only to find the page locked when I was done, because people were not satisfied with the details given.

Stack Overflow ... has some quirks, but if a question has insufficient information for an answer, its probably worth commenting first to get that information. On any other site - I'd recommend a meta post or flag for a reopening if its *actually* answerable but SO's too busy for that I suspect. But gauging viability of a post is an essential skill for success on SE.

What you're asking for is essentially the equivilent of "[choping a seat](https://blog.seedly.sg/using-tissue-packet-to-chope-seats-economical-sense/)" as we say here in singapore. You're already spitballing an answer, you just don't want people to know you did 'in case' the post survived.

I'm not really sure what the value  is there - you're basically doing roughly the same as a draft, you'd lose the post anyway if the question is deleted and no matter what, your time is wasted at a rather quixotic post you spent time on anyway.

In fact - its no different from posting a stub answer, deleting it yourself and undeleting... which while I don't recommend, is possible. This requires no implementation time, uses/abuses existing mechanisms, and is invisible to sub 10k users...

Then again, making the determination of whether a post is viable and helping OP whip it into shape feels like a better use of time for everyone involved and better for the commons than posting answers speculatively